# How to delete the first “text” the each line of the text

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This is the first time I’m asking question there so I’m sorry if is there anything I did wrong

Consider a file names '00.txt' and It contains the following.

```
ai_00_01_01 word01 word01(translated)
ai_00_01_02 word02 word02(translated)

...
ai_00_01_305 word305 word305(translated)
```

P.S. (translated) doesn’t mean there is really a () there, it is just a other language of that line’s word

I hope it changed to this :

```
word01 = word01(translated)
word02 = word02(translated)

...
word305 = word305(translated)
```

The things I tried:

```
cut -f 2- -d ' ' 00.txt > new_file.txt
```

"Give me the second and any other field beyond, using space as a delimiter, from the file.txt file and direct the output to new_file.txt" -by ivanivan in
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515249/how-to-delete-the-first-word-in-each-line-of-a-file
(I think it’s means it is delete the text until the first space?Bad English sorry)

The code I tried just generate a new txt file while nth inside, and the 00 txt file didn’t change anything

Thanks to anyone to help this noob(aka myself)

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux? You've used the `[batch-file]` tag, which is only meant for Windows, but you've tried to use `cut`, which is only available on Linux.

Comment: it is for windows....thats why it does work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is already separated by spaces, you can use a `for /f` loop with the default delimiters:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%A in (00.txt) do echo %%A = %%B >>new_file.txt
```

This takes the second and third thing in each line, stores the second thing in `%%A` and the third thing in `%%B`, and then displays those two things in the format you mention in your question, redirecting it to `new_file.txt`. (Note that if you think you'll run the script more than once, you should add a line before this to delete new_file.txt or else you'll just append the lines to the end of the existing file.)

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this is what you're looking for..

```
% cat stuff.txt
ai_00_01_01 word01 word01(translated)
ai_00_01_02 word02 word02(translated)
ai_00_01_305 word305 word305(translated)
```

`% cut -d' ' -f2- stuff.txt > stuff2.txt`

Output is:

```
% cat stuff2.txt
word01 word01(translated)
word02 word02(translated)
word305 word305(translated)
```

You could then insert the = as desired like so:

```
% sed 's/ / = /' stuff2.txt
word01 = word01(translated)
word02 = word02(translated)
word305 = word305(translated)
```

And then, all together in one line:

`% cut -d' ' -f2- stuff.txt | sed 's/ / = /' > stuff2.txt`

Comment: Thanks for help! (although I have to wait until I arrive home to try does it works)

Comment: sorry...i need a window batch instead of Linux